# Scala nested optionals chaining in object

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I recently started to learn scala ad try to familiarize myself with a simple demo program.

I want to check if a cell has all neighbours. In java this could be accomplished via:

```
public boolean hasFullNeighbourhood() {
    if (top != null && bottom != null && left != null && right != null && 
            top.getLeft() != null && top.getRight() 
            != null && bottom.getLeft() != null 
            && bottom.getRight() != null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Cell is defined as:

```
class Cell(
            val x: Int,
            val y: Int,
            val left: Option[Cell],
            val right: Option[Cell],
            val top: Option[Cell],
            val bottom: Option[Cell],
            var isPainted: Boolean)
```

How can I define a full neighbourhood in scala?
I started like:

```
    def hasFullNeighbourhood(r:Int): Boolean={
        if(r ==0)
          return true
        if (List(top, bottom, left, right).forall(_.isDefined))
          return  true
        else
          return false
  }
```

But how accessing the rest (`x.top, x.bottom, x.left, x.right`) and checking if these are not null/ optional is unclear for me.

I think something like `top.foreach()` would be possible - but if added to the list of optionals it would not fail if this returned `none`.

## edit

I redefined my class as a case class:

```
case class Cell(
            val x: Int,
            val y: Int,
            val left: Option[Cell],
            val right: Option[Cell],
            val top: Option[Cell],
            val bottom: Option[Cell],
            var isPainted: Boolean)
```

Does this mean that

```
  def isMiddleCell()={
    if(List(top, bottom, left, right).forall(_.isDefined))
      true
    else
      false
  }
```

can be rewritten as:

```
  def isMiddleCell(c: Cell) = c match {
    case Cell(_, _, Some(top), Some(bottom), Some(left), Some(right), _) => true
    case _ => false
  }
```

Which still seems a bit strange as I would rather like to check for a given cell if this one is a middle cell an does not specify `Cell.isMiddleCell(givenCell)` but rather `givenCell.isMiddleCell()`

However to implement the

`def hasFullNeughbourhood(radius:Int)` correctly wouldn't I need some more statements as I do not only want to check for immediate neighbours. For me, it is still unclear how to access these. In java I would use `x.getLeft()`and recursively  `x.getLeft().hasFullNeighbourhood(r - 1)`.

```
def hasFullNeighbourhood(c: Cell) = c match {
    case Cell(_, _, Some(top), Some(bottom), Some(left), Some(right), _) => true
    case _ => false
  }
```

## edit2

do I understand correctly that `isMiddleCell` should be implemented as:

```
  def isMiddleCell() = {
    this match {
      case Cell(_, _, Some(top), Some(bottom), Some(left), Some(right), _) => true
      case _ => false
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are typically to good ways to perform an action on the contents of a container in Scala: mapping or decomposition via pattern matching. Pattern matching is the more intuitive one in case of Option if you are not used to functional programming.

To make pattern matching easier, you should define your cell-class as a case class. This gives you pattern matching without having to implement anything yourself and will make the next example nicer. Case-classes are always a good idea for simple data model classes.

```
def hasFullNeighbourhood(c: Cell) = c match {
  case Cell(_,_,Some(top),Some(bottom),Some(left),Some(right),_) => true
  case _ => false
```

I left in the variable names top bottom and so on because you could use those to do something with those values. But as you do not need them for this method I could have just written _ as well. If you do not know pattern matching yet, read up on it. Scala without it isn't fun.

The other way is using map. This is only interesting if you want to do some computation of the stuff in a "container" and put it back into the same kind of container:

```
val possiblyANumber1 = Some(5)
val possiblyANumber2 = Some(5)
val possiblyANumber3 = possiblyANumber1.flatMap(x => possiblyANumber2.map(y => x + y))
```

In this example this allows you to do an addition on two numbers without knowing, whether they actually exist.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. Please can you explain the `_` a bit more are they used instead of `x, y, isPainted`? Please see the edit. I still need some explanation : )

Comment: Yes, basically you can nest these patterns to describe the structure you want. When you want to access the contents of something you put a variable name there, if you do not care about the contents you just put a _. The variable names can be arbitrary names, they do not have to correspond to the names of the parameters or something like that.